# KeyboardResponse Flags

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, windows-registry

I tried to fix randomly "dooubledd letterss in wwords".

Following registry setting seem to work fine, but it adds annoying keypress beep to speakers.

[image: Keyboard Response registry key]

Is there a way to keep these settings and remove the beep? I believe Flags (127) must be set differently, but I could't find meaning of particular bits anywhere.

Note: AutoRepeatDelay/Rate values have been changed from 0 just to keep the feature working with BounceTime set. Default values would be fine for me provided the AutoRepeat feature isn't blocked by BounceTime setting.

Answer (score 0):

I was overlooking the checked "Beep when keys are pressed or accepted" option in the "Set up filter keys" dialog. (It's not so clear in my localisation as it is in English.)

Unchecking it changed the KeyboardResponse Flags value, so the it's **63** now and the settings above work fine without the annoying beep. Resetting other values using `regedit.exe` (+ logoff/restart) was needed as the Accessibility Settings had changed most of the back to their default values.